# prefered way to handel description of µController register bits in c++

Tags: c++

I'm implementing an GUI which communicates with an µController and in the GUI I want to set some registers. An µController register has a size of 8bit and 1 bit can stand for 1 setting or multible bit can stand for 1 setting (if you have more than 2 options to choose from)

For the communication I send the name of the register and the value( 1 char). But for the GUI purpose I want to generate an list containing the description of the individual bits of on register. I was thinking of an 2 dimensional array/vector. First dimension is the bit of the register and the second dimension is the description/stringObject

here is an example:

- bit1 - direction

  - output
  - input
- bit2 - function

  - serial TX
  - analog to digital converter
  - PWM module
  - i2c sda

As a C++ beginner I was wondering if there is a better data structure to solve this problem. For example some kind of custom class/object

Comment: Why?  You can just store it as a `char`, and then let your GUI handle which bit to set or clear.

Comment: the value i handle as a char but i was thinking about how to handle the names for the bits

Comment: Well, how about `7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0`?  That's pretty standard.

Comment: but then you always have to look their function up in the datasheet and this is not very handy

Comment: Your question is becoming increasingly unclear.

Comment: i added an example to the question to be more clear

Comment: Seems like you want a `std::map<int, std::vector<string>>` to store a bunch of strings with the bit number as the key.

Comment: yes this is nearly the way of that what I'm using now (I use a 2D vector now) but I was asking if there is an nicer way/better data construction

Comment: How is it 2D?  You mean like `char [NUM_REGISTERS][MAX_LEN_DESCRIPTION]`?

Comment: like `QVector<QVector<QString> >` first level is bit second is possible descitptions